# White area in Mathematica ListPlot

Tags: graph, wolfram-mathematica, plot, mathematica-8

When I create and plot this list:

```
var = 2;
okList = {{0.8, var, 0.8, 0.8}, {0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9}, {0, 1, 2, 3}};
lp = ListDensityPlot[okList, ColorFunction -> "SandyTerrain"]
```

[image: scaled]

or, unscaled, like this:

```
lp = ListDensityPlot[okList, ColorFunction -> "SandyTerrain",
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: unscaled]

I get a fully coloured square, as I'd expect.

But when I try this:

```
var = 0.8;
list = {{0.8, var, 0.8, 0.8}, {0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9}, {0, 1, 2, 3}};
problem = ListDensityPlot[list, ColorFunction -> "SandyTerrain"]
```

I get a white patch in the corner.

[image: problem]

which plotting with ColorFunctionScaling->False doesn't get rid of

[image: problem_scaled]

The ColorFunction SandyTerrain doesn't have any white in it, so this must be ListDensityPlot not plotting anything in that area.

What could cause this to happen, and how do I stop it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's getting clipped by the automatic plot range calculation.  Try with `PlotRange -> All` or `ClippingStyle -> Automatic`.

Comment: Both work, but the resultant graphs are slightly different. Do you know why?

Comment: On my system (V8.0.1 on OS X), `ClippingStyle -> Automatic` doesn't noticeably change the colors.  `PlotRange -> All` does, because the increased range affects the range that is scaled to [0,1] by `ColorFunctionScaling -> True`.